# In condition not working in mysql query if i use it in 'if condition'

Tags: mysql

```
select group_concat(column) from table where  id=8
```

//this `returns (1,2,3,5,8,9)`

```
select 
      if(5 in (select group_concat(column) from table where  id=8),'a','b');
```

//this `returns b`

```
select 
      if(5 in (5,4,6),'a','b');
```

//this `returns a`

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @juergend the second select statement should also return 'a' not 'b'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `group_concat` in such case.

```
select if(5 in (select `column` from `table` where id=8),'a','b');
```